# How to gather information from an Input Box from within an Excel Plugin using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins, office-addins, vba

I have an Excel Add-In on the Ribbon using C# which grabs data from an API, but the password used for the API may change from time-to-time.

Without going into the myriad of security issues that may exist by gathering the PW for this purpose directly within the add-in, I'm not able to even determine how to display an Input Box, much less get user input entered into it and then pass it back to the program.

I have researched the [_Application.InputBox Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) but can't seem to get that to work. I always get a response such as `The name 'InputBox' does not exist in the type '_Application'`.

The code at this point is very simple, just:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

try
{
    myToken = RequestToken("name@domain.com", "MyPass");
}
catch
{
    Excel._Application.InputBox inputPassword = new Excel.Application.InputBox(); // this is where i get the error
    myToken = RequestToken("name@domain.com", inputPassword.value);
}
```

Again, the purpose here is to try the "default" password. If it fails, ask the user for the updated password (the username won't change) and then we will re-try. Ideally, we'd like to mask the password input, but we can cross that bridge later.

The key here is to not have to re-deploy the entire app with a hard-coded password every time it changes on the server-side.

In a perfect world, I would probably store the updated password somewhere else (.ini file, registry, etc) instead of asking every single time when the "default" password failed. But again, this is a very early first step.

Please keep in mind this is a custom add-in to be used only by a single user, and we are still in testing, so I will probably move to a more robust security method down the road, but for now, this is the best option I have.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure of this since I cannot try it right now, but I don't think you actually instantiate a new InputBox. Besides that, _Application.InputBox is not the same as Application.InputBox

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox.aspx

Comment: @cFrozenDeath - i have tried both `_Application` and also `Application` - i get the same error either way

Comment: @MethodMan - isn't that the same link i posted in the question? the issue is that either i'm not using it correctly in my code, i'm not including the right `using` statement, i've just messed up the syntax terribly, or some other issue i haven't thought of. can you clarify what part of that page has the answer? i can't find ANY examples anywhere from C# add-ins inside excel.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just create a custom (Winforms) dialog and have that pop up?  From there, it's all standard C#.

Comment: @Hambone - you hit the nail on the head. that's the answer. i guess i was forgetting that you can bypass the excel environment and just use the normal winforms from within an excel add-in. - that's the answer.